# Laravel Internal Server Error 500 on custom route

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I freshly installed the newest Laravel 6 a few hours ago. It works well and it show's me the default screen containing "Laravel" and some links to their docs, laracasts, news, blog, ...

But if I'm trying to call any controller, it throws an internal server error (500).

Since the start page works, I don't think it has something todo with the permissions.

APP_KEY is also set in the .env file.
There's not error in the apache log-file, php log-file is empty and enabling php error-logging doesn't work, it still shows "Internal Server Error".
I couldn't find anything on the internet that has exactly the same problem as me.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: What does your server error log say?

Comment: See error logs under storage/logs

Comment: check that the *.env.example* file has been renamed, db connection params are correct (in the *env* file) and directory permissions have been properly set